# Google Spreadsheet jdbc connector

Tags: jdbc, google-sheets, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I need to use Google Spreadsheet with JasperReports Server, for that I need a JDBC connector for Google Spreadsheet.

I found this [project](https://code.google.com/p/gdocjdbc/), but it isn't updated since 2010.

I was wondering if maybe Google Drive has an API for this kind of connections, or some of you knows another way to connect Google Spreadsheet through JDBC drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending some time with this, I found this page: http://www.rssbus.com/jdbc/google-spreadsheet/

They developed this Google Spreadsheet API, and it is very useful for developers who want to test and use their Google Spreadsheets, it is great.

But, the problem is that it has private license, so it can't be used to earn money (not freely) using this JDBC Driver.

I just decided to create my own driver, with the things I need using the Google Spreadsheets API which can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/).

Comment: any luck with that? Found your gh project but it seems empty - https://github.com/eLRuLL/gdrive-jdbc - is it the correct link? Thanks

Comment: I forked from here: https://github.com/enginer/gdrive-hibernate which was a good attempt, but wasn't what I wanted, I think it can be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to push data from your google spreadsheet to your database using the [jdbc connection service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) and [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers).  This obviously is not a JDBC connection and introduces some complexities, but may work for some use cases.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is here: https://github.com/ebarreat/Google-Spreadsheet-JDBC

You are able to establish your connection and which cell you want to start your data on. I hope this helps !

Regards,

EAB